# ASP.NET MVC, HttpContext.Current is null while mocking a request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, session, mocking, nunit

```
public async Task <ActionResult>Select(DWorkingTimeSelection dto) { 
    var session = HttpUtils.GetSeesion<User>("USER"); 
} 

public static T GetSeesion<T>(string key) where T : class
{ 
    if (HttpContext.Current == null) 
    { 
        return default(T);
    }
     return HttpContext.Current.Session[key] as T; 
}

public async Task <ActionResult>Select(DWorkingTimeSelection dto) { 
    var session = HttpUtils.GetSeesion<User>("USER"); 
} 

public static T GetSeesion<T>(string key) where T : class
{ 
    if (HttpContext.Current == null) 
    { 
        return default(T);
    } 
    return HttpContext.Current.Session[key] as T; 
}
```

I use nunti to mock a request.
And I add the SessionStateItemCollection to  the Controller 's ControllerContext . 
I found that the HttpContext.Current is null but the Controller 's  Session[]
is not null because it get from the  Controller 's ControllerContext .
So what should I do to avoid the HttpContext.Current is null while mocking a request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock the HttpContext:

```
    public static HttpContext FakeHttpContext(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
        var httpContext = new HttpContext(request, httpResponse);

        var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer(
            "id", 
            new SessionStateItemCollection(), 
            new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 
            10, 
            true, 
            HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect, 
            SessionStateMode.InProc, 
            false);

        httpContext.Items["AspSession"] =
            typeof(HttpSessionState).GetConstructor(
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, 
                null, 
                CallingConventions.Standard, 
                new[] { typeof(HttpSessionStateContainer) }, 
                null).Invoke(new object[] { sessionContainer });

        return httpContext;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ActionTest()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, "url to the action that you are testing", string.Empty)
        {
            RequestType = "GET"
        };
        HttpContext.Current = FakeHttpContext(request);

        var controller = new YourController();
        //You need the get a Result property since it is an async action
        var result = controller.ActionToTest(//the parameters that your action expects).Result;
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

**EDIT (answering the questions in your comment)**:

In order to get a session you need to call `HttpContext.Current.Session` and not the `HttpContext.Current.Session["id"]` because `HttpContext.Current.Session["id"]` tries to get an `id` key from your session.
Once you store it there it will be available through this call. You can test it:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["id"] = 5;
Assert.AreEqual(HttpContext.Current.Session["id"],5);
```

Regarding the `httpContext.Items` statement:

(From MSDN)`HttpContext.Items` is a key/value collection that can be used to organize and share data between an `IHttpModule` interface and an `IHttpHandler` interface during an HTTP request.

For the statement that you are asking for, simply create a new `HttpSessionState` object by using reflection (because it has only internal constructors) associates it with the `HttpSessionStateContainer` that you created earlier, and store it in `HttpContext.Items` under `AspSession`. And an interesting thing is that `HttpContext.Current.Session` actually is a shortcut to `HttpContext.Items["AspSession"]`. So the assignment of HttpSessionState object to the `AspSession` key is the one that makes `HttpContext.Current.Session` work.

Comment: Well,now the  HttpContext.Current is not null .But i can't get the session from the HttpContext.Current.Session["id"] yet .And could you explain what   is the effect of the Statement - httpContext.Items  please?

Comment: See the latest edit. If my answer was helpful and solved your issue please mark it as an aswer

Comment: About the URL parameter in the HttpRequest instanciation, it can be anything as long as it is well formed : `http://test.com/Controller/Action` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Well,after mocking the HttpContext as Alex Art said .

Calling the following  method will be fine.

```
var sessionItems = new SessionStateItemCollection();
        sessionItems["SessionKey"] = new MyCustomObject();
        SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(fakeHttpContext,
            new HttpSessionStateContainer(SessionNameStorage.Suser,
                          sessionItems,
                          new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(),
                          20000,
                          true,
                          HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                          SessionStateMode.InProc,
                          false
                      ));
```